# Esoteric Hindu Religion?

Tags: history

The late Mohanlal Agrawal composed two volumes entitled "Aghor Nagara Vage" regarding the secret practices and siddhis of Hindu ascetics/yogis.  Why aren't these books discussed more within the Hindu community? They seem to address the esoteric aspect of Hinduism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very word Esoteric means that its not common but limited to a group of people. Such practices of agama are done with high secrecy and are not generally discussed openly. 
But it is certainly discussed by many people related to the sects or paths.

I can recommend some books if you want to explore these paths via books like these,

Blavatsky, H.P.  Foundations of Esoteric Philosophy from the Writings of H.P. Blavatsky.

Arundale G. S.,  Kundalini

C. W. Leadbeater,  Chakras

Aghora: At the Left Hand of God by Robert E. Svoboda

These books are good in understanding many occult and esoteric principles.

Comment: Blavatsky was a Theosophist, not a Hindu. If I remember correctly Leadbeater was also. Theosophy is not Hinduism. None of their practices or beliefs are in line with Hinduism.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda they have written about hinduism and she had masters from india and tibet. Kindly refer her biography.

Comment: Thank you for the references, Mr. Joshi.  I know there was overlapping between Theosophy and the established Eastern religious systems (Hinduism, Buddhism, Taoism).  Moreover, Madame Blavatsky also received tutelage from sages in India as well as Tibet.  These sages probably taught more of the Yogic lineage of knowledge (which is esoteric by its very nature).  Such knowledge may have been part of that "Perennial Philosophy" which was later described by Aldous Huxley.

Comment: @NehalPatel welcome. you can discuss more in the agama chat room in future.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Her sages were 'mahatmas' in the Himalayas and never reveal themselves to the world...all hearsay, no direct guru lineage to anyone. They have very peculiar beliefs that are not at all in line with Hinduism.

Comment: @NehalPatel Huxley's Perennial Philosophy is a reference to the Advaita philosophy. He was a student of Swami Prabhavananda of the Ramakrishna Mission at the time he wrote the book.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda then please tell me lineage of totapuri?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda If dear Nivedita can write about hinduism then why not Madam Blavatsky ?

Comment: Nivedita was an initiated disciple of Swami Vivekananda.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda dashanami tradition does not allow ...

Comment: @RakeshJoshi does not allow what? As a dashanami I am unfamiliar with what you disallow dashanami to do.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda not allowed to initiate women. as per sankara tradition.

Comment: Oh! Unfortunately we did not know this. I will tell all the many dashanamis that I know as they and I have been kept in the dark as to this part of our tradition and have initiated many women. Thank you for enlightening us on our tradition.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda first tell your lineage of sanyasa then we will talk further.